# Forward traffic bound for a certain port over a different interface

Tags: linux, vpn, iptables

My ISP throttles certain types of traffic. To get round this issue I thought about getting myself a VPN connection. Is it possible with the IPTABLES to forward all traffic outbound on port 119 (for example) to my vpn interface pptp0?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Manpage iptables http://unixhelp.ed.ac.uk/CGI/man-cgi?iptables+8

```
-o, --out-interface [!] name
      Name of an interface via which a packet is going to be sent (for
      packets  entering  the  FORWARD, OUTPUT and POSTROUTING chains).
      When the "!" argument is used before  the  interface  name,  the
      sense  is  inverted.   If the interface name ends in a "+", then
      any interface which begins with this name will match.   If  this
      option is omitted, any interface name will match.
```

---

P.S.: Match extensions for ports are:

```
mport
   This module matches a set of source or destination  ports.   Up  to  15
   ports can be specified.  It can only be used in conjunction with -p tcp
   or -p udp.

   --source-ports port[,port[,port...]]
      Match if the source port is one of the given  ports.   The  flag
      --sports is a convenient alias for this option.

   --destination-ports port[,port[,port...]]
      Match  if  the  destination port is one of the given ports.  The
      flag --dports is a convenient alias for this option.

   --ports port[,port[,port...]]
      Match if the both the source and destination ports are equal  to
      each other and to one of the given ports.
```